# True values ​for the selected range of hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
Index          Dates
  0     2017-01-01 23:30:00
  1     2017-01-12 22:30:00
  2     2017-01-20 13:35:00
  3     2017-01-21 14:25:00
  4     2017-01-28 22:30:00
  5     2017-08-01 13:00:00
  6     2017-09-26 09:39:00
  7     2017-10-08 06:40:00 
  8     2017-10-04 07:30:00
  9     2017-12-13 07:40:00
  10    2017-12-31 14:55:00
```

I am trying to select a time range from `5:00:00` to `11:59:00` in the morning, in all months:

`df_new=df['Dates'].between(('2017-01-01 5:00:00'),('2017-12-31  11:59:00'))`

The line above only gives me `True` results, except for the last data. I understand that the error is because I am taking all the dates except the last one. How should I fix the code to have `True` values ​​for the range of hours I said above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to extract only the time part and use leading zeros in the strings:

```
m = (pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
       .between('05:00:00','11:59:00')
     )

out = df[m]
```

output:

```
   Index                Dates
6      6  2017-09-26 09:39:00
7      7  2017-10-08 06:40:00
8      8  2017-10-04 07:30:00
9      9  2017-12-13 07:40:00
```

*NB. to be able to use `between_time` you would need a datetime index:*

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df.set_index('Dates').between_time('05:00:00','11:59:00').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you need to work with `time`, not the whole `dates` range:

```
import datetime
times = df.Dates.dt.time
df[(datetime.time(5) < times) & ( times < datetime.time(11, 59))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `between_time` function in pandas.

```
df_new=df['Dates'].between_time('5:00:00','11:59:00')
```

[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) is the official documentation of it.

Comment: This will raise `TypeError`. `between_time` requires index to be `DatetimeIndex`